# Почему программа не работает? После ввода числа программа замирает

Tags: c++, ряды, факториал

Задача:

> Вычислить сумму ряда с заданной степенью точности Е (0,1^2+0,01^2/2!+
>   0,001^2/3!+ …).

После ввода числа программа замирает и не вычисляет ничего.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float a, b=1, c = 2, s, i = 1,d=1;
    cout << "value for a =";
    cin >> a;
    s = 0;
    do {
        s = s + pow((d / 10),2) / b;
        d = d / 10;
        for (i; c; i++)
        {       
            b = b* i;
        }
        c++;
    }
    while ( c <= a);

    cout << "s=" << s << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Условие выхода из цикла - `c`. Оно равно 2, и не меняется. Получается бесконечный цикл.

Comment: infinite `for` loop https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1040864/

Comment: @Akina, я не понимаю, после каждого цикла к C должна прибавляться единица, почему С не меняется?

Comment: Проще всего такую задачу решить иначе. Вывести число `0.010050167` не зависимо от входного значения. Это сумма вашего ряда в пределе, равная `e^(1/100) - 1`.

Comment: @ Zealint все верно, но только если входное значение не 1 и не 2.

Comment: А почему не верно для 1 и 2? Вам ведь по заданию нужно посчитать ряд с заданной точность, а не с заданным количеством членов. Это разные вещи. Поэтому если ответ более точный, чем заданная точность, то это тоже считается подходящим ответом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Программа не замирает, а вечно выполняет цикл:

```
for (i; c; i++)
{       
      b = b* i;
}
```

так как условие, что `с != 0`, всегда выполняется

Comment: Можете примерно подсказать решение проблемы?

Comment: Joj, все таки здорово, когда сам решаешь, неправда ли?...